# Jquery select element outside of li by ID

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, toggle

im looking to select the follow element by id `toggleThisDiv`. The markup looks like:

```
 <li id="liCategory" runat="server">
       <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCategory" runat="server">
       <span><asp:Literal ID="litCategory" runat="server" Visible="true" /></span>
       <asp:Image ID="imgMan" runat="server" Visible="false" /></asp:HyperLink>
       <asp:Button ID="btnToggleDiv" runat="server" Text="+" Visible="false" />
 </li>

 <div id="toggleThisDiv" runat="server" style="display:none;margin-top:-16px;">
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id*="btnToggleDiv"]').click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

This works when the button is outside of the listitem but this is all inside a repeater and if i leave it like that, all of the buttons created will be next to each other instead of within their associated list item.

I'm looking for something within jQuery that would allow me to select the next div (toggleThisDiv), is this possible?

Thankyou

Comment: This is really, really simple, ID's are unique, so just `$("#toggleThisDiv")` should be enough to select the correct element, otherwise you're doing something wrong.

Comment: The selector is wrong but that will select all of the divs within the repeater though, clicking the button then would hide/show every div within it

Comment: You don't seem to get it, the problem is'nt selecting the element that's next with that particular ID, the problem is that you're generating multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Anyway, `$(this).closest('li').next('#toggleThisDiv').slideToggle(100);` ?

Comment: Is there a way of selecting the unique client id then as otherwise it would effect all of the divs that get rendered out. Your solution works though, thanks.

Comment: The simple fix would be to do : `<div class="toggleThisDiv" .....` as that at least would be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unique ID's, or classes if generating elements where the same identifier will be used.

To target an element outside the current parent of the clicked element you can find the closest parent that matches a selector, and then the next element etc.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('[class*="btnToggleDiv"]').on('click', function () {
       $(this).closest('li').next('div').slideToggle(100);
       return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `closest()`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to select the toggleThisDiv

```
$('#<%= toggleThisDiv.ClientID %>')
```

When the website is generated from your asp code, your IDs will be different than what you have given them.  This is because they are run at server.  Anytime that you are using runat server, use the format above to find the generated ID.

You should use a class inside to repeater though.